# Gamma PnL from Itô's Lemma derivation

Tags: black-scholes, itos-lemma, gamma, pnl

The change in a call portfolio ($f$), derived from Itô's Lemma, is:
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t &=r\left( f-rS\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}\right)\mathrm{d} t, \\
\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+rS\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2} -rf&=0
\end{align*}

where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ denotes theta, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}$ denotes delta and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2}$ denotes gamma.

So gamma's PnL would be $\frac{1}{2}\Gamma \sigma^2 \mathrm{d}S^2$, where $\mathrm{d}S^2$ is the underlying price's change.

But why is gamma's PnL in reallity $\frac{1}{2}\Gamma \mathrm{d}S^2$, and not the previous formula? Why shouldn't volatility be included gamma's PnL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2} dS^2 \approx  \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S^2} dt$$

(for small $dt$, ignoring $(dt)^2$ terms )

$\sigma$ is embedded in $dS = \mu S dt + \sigma S dW$ and
$$ dS^2 = \mu^2 S^2 dt^2 + 2\mu \sigma S^2 dt dW + \sigma^2 S^2 dt \approx \sigma^2 S^2 dt$$

You picked up $1/2\Gamma \sigma^2$ from the PDE and for some (unknown) reason you multiplied it by $dS^2$. You can only multiply it by $S^2$ as in the PDE (to get PnL per unit of time) or by $S^2 dt$ like in the SDE (to get dollar PnL).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't get why, even for small $dt$, the volatility variable dissapears. 
Could you elaborate a little bit about it, please?

Comment: @DUM03 Just added an explanation.

Comment: Tks, things are becoming clearly.

Why we have 

$≈ σ^2S^2 dt$, instead of $≈ σ^2S^2 dW^2$?

It would be because $dW  = e√dt $, that turns into $e^2*dt$, where "$e$" follows a Wiener process? If it is correct, what should we do with $e^2$?

Thanks

Comment: See this link for a formal explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81865/wiener-process-db2-dt

Comment: Take $(dW)^2 = dt$ as a catculation simplification of covariation of Ito processes.

Comment: Great, tks for the help!

Comment: @DUM03 Great. Don't forget to accept the answer so I get the point bounty! :)